# There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sass-rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error while starting rails server.

```
C:\Ruby22-x64\WebAppRails>rails s C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sass-rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/WebAppRails/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Here are the gems I'm using:

```
C:\Ruby22-x64\WebAppRails>bundle show
```

Gems included by the bundle:

- actionmailer (4.2.6)
- actionpack (4.2.6)
- actionview (4.2.6)
- activejob (4.2.6)
- activemodel (4.2.6)
- activerecord (4.2.6)
- activesupport (4.2.6)
- arel (6.0.3)
- binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
- builder (3.2.2)
- bundler (1.11.2)
- byebug (8.2.5)
- coffee-rails (4.1.1)
- coffee-script (2.4.1)
- coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
- concurrent-ruby (1.0.1)
- debug_inspector (0.0.2)
- erubis (2.7.0)
- execjs (2.6.0)
- globalid (0.3.6)
- i18n (0.7.0)
- jbuilder (2.4.1)
- jquery-rails (4.1.1)
- json (1.8.3)
- loofah (2.0.3)
- mail (2.6.4)
- mime-types (3.0)
- mime-types-data (3.2016.0221)
- mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
- minitest (5.8.4)
- multi_json (1.11.3)
- nokogiri (1.6.7.2)
- rack (1.6.4)
- rack-test (0.6.3)
- rails (4.2.6)
- rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
- rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
- rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
- railties (4.2.6)
- rake (11.1.2)
- rdoc (4.2.2)
- sass (3.4.22)
- sass-rails (5.0.4)
- sdoc (0.4.1)
- sprockets (3.6.0)
- sprockets-rails (3.0.4)
- sqlite3 (1.3.11)
- thor (0.19.1)
- thread_safe (0.3.5)
- tilt (2.0.2)
- turbolinks (2.5.3)
- tzinfo (1.2.2)
- tzinfo-data (1.2016.4)
- uglifier (3.0.0)
- web-console (2.3.0)

gem version is 2.4.5.1 and ruby version is 2.2.4

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: can you show your `WebAppRails/config/application.rb` file?

Comment: require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Railapp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end

Comment: can you show your gemfile ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 5.0.3'
```

And do

```
bundle update sass-rails
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem got solved when I installed proper version of Ruby for my freshly cloned Rails app - I had 2.4.1 installed but my app needed 2.3.