# `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sass-rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I finish to install rails 5 at my ubuntu system(16.04.2 LTS) and I'm with this error when I try to run rails server command.

```
`rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sass-rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
```

Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant Sass::Script
Did you mean?  ScriptError

When I write bundle update, the prompt show me this message:

```
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
```

and then it update well ... and show ~≳ Using sass-rails 5.0.6

Please help-me guys, regards!

Comment: There is no issue, maybe you forgot to put `'sass-rails'` in your gemfile, and the `bundle update` fixed the problem. Also, the `tzinfo-data` message is a warning, you don't need that gem in linux, only in windows

Comment: If the gem is in gemfile the message of tzinfo-data appear and the rails server doesn't works with the message 

`rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sass-rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant Sass::Script

When I comment the line gem 'sass-rails', rails s works well

Comment: I didn't saw in the post that you had to comment the line, maybe you've to update the gem, there is a similar post recently about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963056/there-was-an-error-while-trying-to-load-the-gem-sass-rails-bundlergemrequi